# Getting error "Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string."

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to php. Help me solving this problem. I have tried all the solutions given in website. but it is not working on my code.

```
$query= "select * from login where username='$uname' and password= '$password'";    
$result = mysqli_query("$query","$conn") or die(mysqli_error("$conn"));

$row = mysqli_fetch_rows($result);
if($row == 1)
{

    $_SESSION['valid'] = $uname;

    header("location: welcomeuser.php");    
}
```

Comment: Don't put quotes around `$conn`.

Comment: @IncredibleHat How this question could be asked with the same title?

Comment: To add what @Barmar said: don't put variables (such as `$query`) in strings as they will attempt to be passed as the string and not the variable. You want: `$query= "select * from login where username='" . $uname . "' and password= '" . $password . "';";    
$result = mysqli_query($query, $conn) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: @IncredibleHat The title may be the same, but the problem and solution are completely different.

Comment: Nevermind the obvious sql injection vulnerabilities too, and putting quotes around $query, and storing passwords in plain text, and ...

Comment: @Barmar I retracted it, after reading through both more closely, and seeing the real issue at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$conn` is an object. When you put the variable inside quotes in

```
$result = mysqli_query("$query","$conn") or die(mysqli_error("$conn"));
```

it tries to convert it to a string so it can interpolate it into the quoted string. But that's not generally valid, unless the class provides a conversion method; and even if it does, `msyqli_query()` and `mysqli_error()` expect an object as their first arguments, not a string.

It should be:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Note that you had the arguments to `mysqli_query()` in the wrong order.

There's also no need to put quotes around `$conn`, since it's already a string.

You should also learn to use prepared statements and parameters instead of substituting variables into the SQL string.